# OpenSSL: Is it possible to view the EC Named Curve without the ecparam file?

Tags: security, openssl, key-pair

Is there an OpenSSL command to derive the Named Curved that was used in the generation of an EC Key Pair?

I generate the parameters into a PEM file here:

`openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -out secp256k1.pem`

Then verify the Named Curve used by typing:

`openssl ecparam -in secp256k1.pem -text -noout`

But how to achieve the same when you have only the Private.pem and Public.pem and NOT the ecparam file?

`openssl pkey -in user1Key.pem -text -noout` worked on keys I generated with the Command-Line OpenSSL tool but not the C libraries.  When I run this command against the PEM files - I generated using C - I get everything but NOT the short ecparam name.  I get the Private, Public, Seed, Prime, A, B, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

My C code was generating an EC Pair with OpenSSL APIs where the **explicit parameters** for the Curve was set.  When I did the same with OpenSSL's command line tool, I did not set the explicit parameter.

To get around the issue - to verify both sides were deriving the same Key - I used the following OpenSSL command line tool:

`openssl ecparam -in ec_paramprime256v1.pem -genkey -noout -out appKey.pem -param_enc explicit`

If this has impacted you, I suggest you investigate OpenSSL's wiki for **set_asn1_flag**